# How to make two columns (40% 60%) grid elements the same height?

Tags: html, css

Using the CSS Grid system, I have two columns; first is 40% and second 60% using grid-template-column. The first column is made of text, the second of an img; how to make both columns the same height?

```css
.container
{
    max-width: 1130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section
{
    padding: 30px;
}

#sec-1
{
    padding: 0;
}

.sec-1 img
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#sec-1 .wrapper
{
    padding: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #a454fd, #2b05df);
    color: white;
}

section[id^="sec"] h1
{
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#sec-1 a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
}

#sec-1 a:hover
{
    color: #0000cc;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #sec-1
    {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/webfontkit-roboto/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="sec-1">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>DISCOVER SOMETHING BRAND NEW</h1>  
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus veniam, atque totam rerum repellat velit quae omnis consequatur debitis harum laudantium at laborum iure! Veritatis accusantium assumenda mollitia quas consequuntur!</p>
                <div>
                    <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="https://placehold.jp/375x271.png" alt="p-2">
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As others have noted giving the image a height of 100% might produce the effect you want unless you desire your wrap on smaller screens to differ from a normal responsive flow (image below when screen narrows).

Answer (score 0):

Consider applying `height: 100%` to the `<img>` element:

```css
.container
{
    max-width: 1130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

section
{
    padding: 30px;
}

#sec-1
{
    padding: 0;
}

.sec-1 img
{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#sec-1 .wrapper
{
    padding: 50px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #a454fd, #2b05df);
    color: white;

}

section[id^="sec"] h1
{
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#sec-1 a 
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    display: block;
    width: 115px;
}

#sec-1 a:hover
{
    color: #0000cc;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {



}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {




}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {


    #sec-1
    {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
    }


    img
    {
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Elements</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.2/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/webfontkit-roboto/stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="sec-1">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1>DISCOVER SOMETHING BRAND NEW</h1>  
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus veniam, atque totam rerum repellat velit quae omnis consequatur debitis harum laudantium at laborum iure! Veritatis accusantium assumenda mollitia quas consequuntur!</p>
                <div>
                    <a href="#"> CONTACT US </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="https://placehold.jp/375x271.png" alt="p-2">
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to implement required functionality of making height of content column and image column same in grid page, the following CSS code can be used:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #sec-1 img
    {
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```